# Flutter Create Screen (TABVIEW)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a tab view at the top, which has 5 plus buttons - when a user clicks on a plus button, a dialog box should pop up, asking for the workout name. Then, when the user inputs the workout name, the name should take the place of the clicked plus button. However there is one rule with this:

- A plus button can only be clicked if the preceding one has been filled in - for example if I click button 2 without putting a workout name in for button 1, it shouldn't work

In addition, I want it so that the text boxes are clickable, and for now I just want the name of the workout to be printed. Everything I said above I have already done, but I need your help converting it to a tab view format so I can swipe side to side to go to the next workout. In addition I don't know how to implement the rule right now so I need some help with that too.

TLDR: **I need help making this screen in a tab view, and also need help implementing the rule I said above in the middle**

EDIT: An example of what I want is if you go to the app My Workout Plan and then go to their My Workout tab

My code is below, and I've also included a screen shot of what it should look like (for now everything is hardcoded)

IMAGE:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHpy8.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workout_app/Screens/Components/Widgets/footer.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:workout_app/colors.dart';
import 'package:workout_app/Screens/Components/Widgets/footer.dart';

class workout_page extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Main createState() => _Main();
}

class _Main extends State<workout_page> {
  @override
  var workoutMap = [
    {
      'name': 'arms',
      'exercises': [
        {
          'name': 'Bicep Curl',
          'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep']
        },
        {
          'name': 'Preacher Curl',
          'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep']
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'name': 'legs',
      'exercises': [
        {
          'name': 'Squat',
          'musclesworked': ['quadriceps', 'hamstrings']
        },
        {
          'name': 'Lunges',
          'musclesworked': ['quadriceps', 'hamstrings']
        }
      ]
    },
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ];
  late List<String> workoutnames;
  List<String> workouts = List.filled(5, '');
  int lastFilledIndex = -1;
  bool showContainer = false;
  String selectedWorkout = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    workoutnames = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < workoutMap.length; i++) {
      workoutnames
          .add(workoutMap[i]['name'] == null ? '' : workoutMap[i]['name']);
    }
    // Find the first non-empty workout name in workoutnames
    selectedWorkout =
        workoutnames.firstWhere((name) => name.isNotEmpty, orElse: () => '');
    if (selectedWorkout.isNotEmpty) {
      showContainer = true;
    }
  }

  void _showDialog(int index) {
    String newWorkout = '';

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Enter Workout Name'),
          content: TextField(
            maxLength: 7,
            onChanged: (value) {
              newWorkout = value;
            },
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Add'),
              onPressed: () {
                if (newWorkout.isNotEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    workoutnames[index] = newWorkout;
                    selectedWorkout = newWorkout;
                    showContainer = true;
                  });
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: size.height * .06,
                titleSpacing: 15,
                pinned: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                centerTitle: false,
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: List.generate(workoutnames.length, (index) {
                      final isClickable = index <= lastFilledIndex + 1;
                      final workoutName = workoutnames[index];
                      final isWorkoutEmpty = workoutName.isEmpty;
                      return Expanded(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: isWorkoutEmpty
                                ? () => _showDialog(index)
                                : () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedWorkout = workoutName;
                                      showContainer = true;
                                    });
                                  },
                            child: isWorkoutEmpty
                                ? Container(
                                    width: 30, // Adjust the width as needed
                                    height: 30, // Adjust the height as needed
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 187, 255),
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    ),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.add,
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : Container(
                                    width: 48,
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 10,
                                    ), // Adjust the width as needed
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border(
                                        bottom: BorderSide(
                                          width: selectedWorkout == workoutName
                                              ? 1.5
                                              : 0,
                                          color: selectedWorkout == workoutName
                                              ? Colors.blue
                                              : Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        workoutName,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: selectedWorkout == workoutName
                                              ? Colors.black
                                              : Colors.blue,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (showContainer)
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(
                    height: size.height * .3,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
                    child: Text(
                      selectedWorkout,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
          Footer(tab: 'Workout'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```